# Web Sharing on Mountain Lion

Tags: web, osx-mountain-lion

I'm looking to set up a web server on my Mac. According to [this site](http://macs.about.com/od/networking/qt/websharing.htm), Mac OS X has a built in web server, but according to [this site](http://macs.about.com/od/usingyourmac/qt/Web-Hosting-With-Mountain-Lion.htm), a lot of the control to it was disabled in Mountain Lion. The second site points to [yet another site](http://clickontyler.com/blog/2012/02/web-sharing-mountain-lion/) that offers some software to restore the full web sharing capabilities of my Mac. I installed this software and turned web sharing on through System Preferences>>Web Sharing. Then, as indicated by the directions in the first link, I created a ~/username/Site/index.html file with the text "Hello World". However, when I access localhost/index.html through my browser, I get the text "It works!". What do I have to do to be able to edit what I access through localhost/index.html (or some other URL that I can use locally). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document root is /Library/WebServer/Documents.

If you want to turn Mountain Lion into a full featured server you can purchase OSX Server from the app store, it's $19.95

Comment: Thanks! (I edited your response to fix some capitalization errors in the filepath.)

Comment: No problem with the edit, altho unless you've reformatted your HD to be case sensitive, OSX is by default not case sensitive.  What I posted with the output from pwd ... either way will get you there.